# Symfony + WSSE: Why is the nonce cache folder 20GB in size?

Tags: symfony, caching, nonce, wsse

I am working on a `Symfony 3.4` based projects which uses a [WSSE authentication as described in the Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).

Each nonce is stored as separate file in the cache dir `myProject/var/cache/prod/security/nonces`. Probelm is, that this dir becomes very, very large in size. The project has been up and running and the nonces already use **almost 20GB in disk space**!

```
$ cd myProject/var/cache/prod/security/
$ du -sch *
19G    nonces
19G    total
```

This seems pretty much to me... I tried to figure out how many nonces are stored and used the following command to count the files:

```
$ cd myProject/var/cache/prod/security/nonces
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
4697417
```

Even for 4.7 million files 19GB seems pretty much. Each file would need to have a size of roughly about 4KB. However, as far as I can tell each file has only 10B...

```
$ cd myProject/var/cache/prod/security/nonces
$ ls -lh
-rw-r----- 1 user nobody 10 Jul 25 16:46 'MWFiYWM5YjAiOTRyOWRmZA=='
-rw-r----- 1 user nobody 10 Jul  1 19:41 'MWFiYWNiYTflNTdhLGYwYQ=='
-rw-r----- 1 user nobody 10 Sep 29 11:05 'MWFiYWNkNzEjZfFlCjM0OQ=='
...
```

I know that there is a difference between file size and consumed diskspace. However, `du` also shows 10B of disk space:

```
$ du -sb --apparent-size MWFiYWNkNzEjZfFlCjM0OQ==
10
```

**So, how can the files use 19G of disk space while each files only uses 10B? Am I missing something? Or did I not use the commands correctly?**

**Isn't there a better to store the nonces?**

**Of course I could delete the cache every now and then. However, this would make the nonces pretty much useless, wouldn't it?**

Comment: I don't know about WSSE, but the size of on the disk may depend on your disk block size.
Maybe you can store nonces in a database ?

Comment: @FabienPapet Thanks. As described in the question I know that there is difference between file size and disk space due to the block size. However, use `du` should show the consumed disk space, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know about the `du` usage, you can try on superuser site, they'll have an answer

Comment: Yes `du` reports the consumed diskspace. In your case thats 4k per file, because 4k is the block size of your filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Filesize

`du` reports the size of disk space that is consumed. **Disk space is allocated in blocks**. So the minimal space a file can occupy is 1 block. In your case the block size of your filesystem seems to be 4kb. Therefore ~4.7 million files with a size of 10byte consume 4700000 * 4kb, thats arround 19gb.

### How long to store nonces

Nonces are usually cached for a few minutes. The symfony cookbook you mentioned recommends a nonce ttl of 5 minutes. Here is an extract of that documentation

```
class WsseProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
  protected function validateDigest($digest, $nonce, $created, $secret)
    {
        // Check created time is not in the future
        if (strtotime($created) > time()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Expire timestamp after 5 minutes
        if (time() - strtotime($created) > 300) {
            return false;
        }

        // Try to fetch the cache item from pool
        $cacheItem = $this->cachePool->getItem(md5($nonce));

        // Validate that the nonce is *not* in cache
        // if it is, this could be a replay attack
        if ($cacheItem->isHit()) {
            // In a real world application you should throw a custom
            // exception extending the AuthenticationException
            throw new AuthenticationException('Previously used nonce detected');
        }

        // Store the item in cache for 5 minutes
        $cacheItem->set(null)->expiresAfter(300);
        $this->cachePool->save($cacheItem);

        // Validate Secret
        $expected = base64_encode(sha1(base64_decode($nonce).$created.$secret, true));

        return hash_equals($expected, $digest);
    }
}
```

The nonces are added to the cache-pool with a ttl of 5 minutes.
Keeping the nonces longer than the time you consider the created field valid (five minutes in this example `if (time() - strtotime($created) > 300)`) doesn't add any extra security, because as soon as the creation date becomes outdated a replayed request can be rejected based on the created timestamp.